# Prestashop / Smarty Template converting to standard php

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop

Im trying to convert a prestashop theme into a wordpress theme and im having issues understanding the smarty template lingo.

I was wondering if someone could tell me in standard php syntax what the following means.

```
{if isset($css_files)}
    {foreach from=$css_files key=css_uri item=media}
        {if preg_match("#global#",$css_uri)}
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="{$css_uri|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}"  id="global-style" type="text/css" media="{$media|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" />
        {else}
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="{$css_uri|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" type="text/css" media="{$media|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" />
        {/if}
    {/foreach}
{/if}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (isset($css_files)) {
  foreach ($css_files as $css_uri => $media) {
    if (preg_match("#global#", $css_uri)) {
      echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="' . htmlspecialchars($css_uri, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . '" id="global-style" type="text/css" media="' . htmlspecialchars($media, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . '" />';
    }
    else
    {
      echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="' . htmlspecialchars($css_uri, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . '" type="text/css" media="' . htmlspecialchars($media, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . '" />';
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that, just one question, if i have a custom theme, where is the css_files variable set? .. I see alot of css files in my theme but no where have they been added as code

Comment: @BigJobbies The `css_files` array is set in `classes/controller/FrontController.php` by the `addCSS` method.